# Azure SQL queries with same order returning different resultsets

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I hope that some SQL Server genius has any idea what can cause this misbehavior. Executing the following two queries I get different records:

```
declare @__p_0 int = 50
declare @__p_1 int = 1

SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[DescriptionHtml], [a].[Name], [a].[SummaryHtml]
FROM [Appointment] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[DateDeleted] IS NULL
ORDER BY [a].[Name]
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
      
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Name]
FROM [Appointment] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[DateDeleted] IS NULL
ORDER BY [a].[Name]
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
```

It seams to be somehow related to the pagesize since as soon as I remove any other columns in the first query the record is the same like in the second. As you sure may suspect this behavior is pure horror with paged resultsets and even worse with EFCore's `AsSplitQuery`.

Running this query local on my `SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition (15.0.2080.9)` does not bring up this error, running on `Azure SQL Server 12.0.2000.8` I'm facing this problem. If one wants to reproduce it I could try to isolate the required data in the tables.

Comment: Name doesn’t sound like a stable column to order on- if there are multiple rows with the same name then their order is unpredictable and all sorts of factors may influence the server reading them back in one order over another, including which columns you select. You should include enough order by columns so that it’s distinct. E.g Name, Id. 

What is the query you are building in code?

Comment: By the way, you may be interested in using [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) instead, it is much more performant than Rowset Pagination. You do need a unique set of columns to order on though

Comment: The query gets generated by EFCore so I'd probably need to add the Id column. But I though SQL Server ensures a constant result set indemendet of the columns selected? I never had this behavior with a "regular" SQL Server, just facing it with Azure for the first time.

I'd need to refactor my whole code since tables often get sorted by non unique columns. Is this really a fact? Is sorting by non unique columns not reliable?

Comment: I’m pretty sure neither guarantee a constant order if an order by is not supplied or if the order by is not unique. In  practice, you may often see quite a stable order but it will be due to factors that aren’t easily controllable, such as their position disk (which might be in PK/creation order but not necessarily) or the indexes it decides to use etc. Certainly the I/O behind the scenes on Azure might be different enough that you see the problem there more often but it’s not impossible on regular SQL Server

Comment: Thank you very much! I told the EFCore team about this possible behavior, guess pretty many could fall in this huge pit!

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24690

Answer (score 0):

This is an intentional behavior and queries are not guaranteed to be ordered identical for non unique columns. This can be caused by many reasons (indexes, physical order, etc. pp.) and differ from request to request. The solution is to always order by PK last, if the wanted order is not unique.